# Android Instrumentation tests - Session terminated, terminating shell... ...terminated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, android-emulator, gitlab-ci, android-instrumentation

I have an Android project that I want to run Instrumentation tests on in a GCP Gitlab-runner. I have virtualization enabled for that runner. I installed Android SDK tools, created a avd based on 'pixel' device, started on emulator using that avd.
My avd create command(where EMULATOR_IMAGE is system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86): `echo n | avdmanager --verbose create avd -n Pixel --device "pixel" -k "${EMULATOR_IMAGE}" --abi "x86" -f`.

My emulator start command: `emulator -avd Pixel -no-window -no-audio -no-boot-anim -dns-server 8.8.8.8 &`
After verifying that the emulator is running, I'm giving my gradle command to run Instrumentation tests. I can see message in log: `Starting 119 tests on Pixel(AVD) - 11`
After a few seconds, I see the below message:

`Session terminated, terminating shell... ...terminated.`

If I see the report for failed tests, I can see the below error:
`com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException: executeRemoteCommand interrupted with immediate timeout via interruption.`

What would be a good way to approach this problem ? How can I verify why the tests are failing. Does giving Google's DNS help the emulator connect to the internet without any issues ? Is there a good way to verify if emulator is connected(I cannot make significant changes to code as I'm in DevOps and not the developer) ?

Comment: Hey! I understand that you are running your Gitlab-runner in Kubernetes right?

Comment: @Chris32 No. Our runner is in a VM.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand then by "VM" you mean a Compute Engine VM right?

Comment: @Chris32 Yes. The same.

Comment: i'm seeing same message, it's inside vm running inside proxmox host, process dies in different places, sometimes in middle of cp command